# Possible to virtualize OpenGL > 2?

Tags: opengl, virtualization

I'm working on an app that will run on linux with an NVIDIA graphics card using OpenGL.  I would like to be able to run that environment virtualized (albeit very slow) for testing.  I've got linux running in VMWare but with mesa the vernon of OpenGL I get is only 2.  Is there anyway to virtualize a higher version of OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Funnel money and effort into [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) to boost work on the [OpenGL 3+ state tracker(s)](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/plain/docs/GL3.txt).</strike>

Alternatively, petition [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/) for a reference implementation.

[As of Mesa 20.2 `llvmpipe` supports OpenGL 4.5](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/blob/mesa-20.2.0/docs/features.txt#L213).